# Android Refactor Menu Class

Tags: java, android

I have a menu class for an android application and I feel I could refactor it as I have practically the same method 4 times, please see below:

```
public abstract class MenuActivity extends SherlockActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar ab = getSherlock().getActionBar();
    SherlockHelper.setupActionBar(ab, this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return createMenu(this, menu);
}

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockActivity aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = ((SherlockActivity) aActivity).getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
}   

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockListActivity aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = aActivity.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
} 

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = aActivity.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
} 

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockFragment aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = aActivity.getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
}    
}
```

I want to change this so I only have ONE method not FOUR! To do this I assume I pass in a generic object, but I don't actually know what to pass in! Do I need to change the methods to a dynamic one instead of static?

Any Help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You only need `Context` to create what you need in body of all of your methods.

Extract the same comde in one method that takes `Context` as argument so you can call this method as many times as you need.

```
public static boolean createMenu(Context context, Menu menu) {
    // Here is your code that use context
}

public static boolean whateverMethodYouWant(WhatEverClass smth, Menu menu) {
    // Get/cast or smth else to get Context from smth.
    Context context = castOrExtractContext(smth);
    return createMenu(context, menu);
}
```

In this case it's error free code, because you handle all stuff about WhatEverClass that user passes to you and he have no idea about what you perform inside your method.

Comment: Could you show me an example please? I think I know what you mean, In my method do something like `public static boolean createMenu(Context context, Menu menu)`?

Answer (score -1):

Alright, since you have two kind of different answers I can show you the difference and when to use which.

First off, what you want to do when you have multiple methods that you want to combine into one is that you want to find a *common denominator*. That is, something that all methods have in common.

To find the common denominator(s) you examine the methods that you want to turn into one.

```
public static boolean createMenu(SherlockActivity aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = ((SherlockActivity) aActivity).getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
}
```

From this method there are two objects that are created from parameters; **MenuInflater inflater** and **(Context)aActivity**. The MenuInflater is accessed from a method in Activity and the Context is cast from an Activity. Thus, providing your new (combined) method with an Activity will provide the new method with enough information to be able to do what the four others have done.

When you have found the common denominator(s) there are two cases:

1. The parameters already have all common denominators
2. The parameters does not have all common denominators

**Solution for the first case:**

You know that all your classes can access an Activity. Thus, you let your new method take one Activity and one Menu as parameter:

```
public static boolean createMenu(Activity aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = aActivity.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
}
```

Now the four other methods can call this one.

```
public static boolean createMenu(SherlockActivity aActivity, Menu menu){
    return createMenu((Activity) aActivity, menu); // Explicitly call method with Activity as argument
}

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockListActivity aActivity, Menu menu){
    return createMenu((Activity) aActivity, menu); // Explicitly call method with Activity as argument
} 

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity aActivity, Menu menu){
    return createMenu((Activity) aActivity, menu); // Explicitly call method with Activity as argument
} 

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockFragment aActivity, Menu menu){
        return createMenu(aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), menu); // Explicitly call method with Activity as argument
}
```

**Solution for the second case:**

Suppose that not all of the four classes extend Activity or can be cast as a Context. Then we need a way to tell the new method how to access an Activity and Context from the class that we are providing. For this, we use an *interface*. The interface has a number of methods that explicitly tells that the class implementing this interface can provide the information promised by the interface (as long as the class implementation is correct of course).

```
public interface SherlockInterface {
    public Activity getActivity();
}
```

Now, *you let all your classes implement this interface*. **How** the classes implement the interface methods is up to them, but somehow they must provide these methods.

Your new method knows that it can use the SherlockInterface (since it provides an Activity).

```
public static boolean createMenu(SherlockInterface iface, Menu menu){

    Activity aActivity = iface.getActivity();
    MenuInflater inflater = aActivity.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
}
```

Since all your classes implement the interface, this method will be called by java, and you will only have one method instead of four.

Hope this explation helped!

Comment: If you are sure that all classes implements your interface, you even don't need last 4 methods, you have to pass only interface in argument in this case.